# Unset Shipping for particular order?

Tags: 8, commerce

I have used the commerce shipping module in my site, now I want to unset the shipping for a particular order.

How Could I achieve this?

Comment: What is drupal version?

Comment: am Using Drupal 8

Comment: What is particular about that order for which you want to unset shipping? Is it its type, any particular field or something else?